# How to check if category has grand parent or Category has grand children?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have category table which looks like this...

```
Id ParentId Name
1  0        a
2  1        a1
3  2        a2
```

how to check if a2 has grand parent or a has grand children? in sql?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: i have tagged that i am using sqlserver

Comment: How many levels are there for child/parent relation? or undefined?

Comment: 3 is maximum count of levels

Answer (score 0):

To find the grandparent row of `a2` you can do:

```
select c.*
from t a
join t b on b.id = a.parentid
join t c on c.id = b.parentid
where a.name = 'a2'
```

To find the grandchildren rows of `a2` you can do:

```
select c.*
from t a
join t b on b.parentid = a.id
join t c on c.parentid = b.id
where a.name = 'a2'
```

Comment: I think in the second query, it should be c.name='a2'.

Comment: In both queries you start with table `a`. In the first one you walk "up" the hierarchy, while in the second one you walk the hierarchy down.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, in first case it's parent(a)-->b, parent(b)-->c, so, grandparent is C (of a), while in second case, son(a)-->b, son(b)-->c, so, C is the grandchildren (of  a). I was confused because there was no result for second query (and that's because a2 has no grandchildren, a has).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *recursive* cte approach to check grand parent or child children :

```
with r_cte as (
     select t.id, t.parentid, t.name
     from table t
     where t.name = 'a2'
     union all
     select tm.id, tm.parentid, tm.name
     from table tm inner join
          r_cte r
          on r.parentid = tm.id
)
select rc.*
from r_cte rc;
```

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer... what i want to know is that when i set t.Name = 'a2' it should give me if it has grand children for instance: a parent category has a1 child and a1 has a2 child category and also i have b parent category which has b2 category but b2 has no child category... what i want to do is that when i set t.Name = 'a' it should return true when i set t.Name ='b' it should return false, because it has no child category